# Vowels in string C++

Tags: c++, string

I should type in  string and my program should  reorganize elements so Serbian vowels (a,o,i,e,u) should be first elements and then  consonants .My idea was to copy vowels in second string and consonants in third and then make one string (using strcat and vowels and consonant string) but that didn't work as planned... Any ideas what to change or how to do it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[50],s2[50];
    char vowels[50];
    char consonant[50];
    int k=0,f=0; 

    printf("Type string:\n");
    gets(s);


    for(int i;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        if(s[i]={'A','O','I','E','U','a','o','i','e','u'}) s[i]=vowels[k],k++;
        else  s[i]=consonant[f],f++;
    }

    strcat(vowels,consonant);

     printf("%s",vowels);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you think this line does?

    `if(s[i]={'A','O','I','E','U','a','o','i','e','u'}`

Comment: I think your idea works, but `s[i] = {...}` is not how you check if a value is one of a number of values. You can either do lots of `if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'o' ... )` or use something like `strchr` to see if a character is part of string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it depends on c++ which version you got...its extended list of elements...still it may be problem will try to change it

Comment: @MatsPetersson well in school my professor gave this as example of extended lists for searching so l  thought its easier to use this instead of listing all elements if if()||...

Comment: @user3127589 - That is not legal C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just changed to if()||... and now I gain some random symbols printed...sometimes I just got no luck :D

Comment: @user3127589 - There is so much more wrong with your code.  One thing is that strcat(vowels, consonant) is undefined behavior since consonant is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, and strcat() works when the string is properly null-terminated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie l can evade it  by simply printing two stings next to each other(printf("%s%s",vowels,consonant) but l still get random symbols so mistake must be somewhere in for loop

Answer (score 1):

`if(s[i]={'A','O','I','E','U','a','o','i','e','u'})` is not a legal C++

Consider using [***`std::strchr`***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr), and use your C -style logic.

A better way of partioning (vowels and consonants) could be :
by using [***`std::partition`***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) (since its tagged for C++ )

```
bool is_vowel(char ch) { return std::strchr("aeiouAEIOU", ch) != NULL ; }

std::string s; //use std::string
std::string::const_iterator p =
        std::partition(s.begin(), s.end(), 
                       std::ptr_fun(is_vowel));
```

See demo [here](http://ideone.com/qaJceD)

Also, avoid using `gets`, use `std::getline` with C++

Comment: For the record, `std::ptr_fun` is now deprecated, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun

Answer (score 1):

Though you targeted your question with C++ it seems that you deal with C.

Try the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    const size_t N = 50;
    const char vowels[] = { 'A', 'O', 'I', 'E', 'U', 'a', 'o', 'i', 'e', 'u', '\0' };
    char s[N], s1[N], s2[N];

    printf( "Type string: " );
    fgets( s, N, stdin );

    char *p1 = s1,*p2 = s2;
    for ( char *q = s; *q; ++q )
    {
        if ( strchr( vowels, *q ) )
        {
            *p1++ = *q;
        }
        else
        {
            *p2++ = *q;
        }
    }

    *p1 = '\0';
    *p2 = '\0';

    strcpy( s, s1 );
    strcat( s, s2 );

    printf( "result string: \"%s\"", s );

    return 0;
}
```

If your compiler does not support C99 then change the loop the following way

```
    char *q = s, *p1 = s1,*p2 = s2;
    for ( ; *q; ++q )
```

And place all variable definitions in the beginning of main

Also substitute

```
const size_t N = 50;
```

for

```
#define N 50
```

As for your code then this construction

```
for(int i;i<strlen(s);i++)
{
    if(s[i]={'A','O','I','E','U','a','o','i','e','u'}) s[i]=vowels[k],k++;
    else  s[i]=consonant[f],f++;
}
```

is invalid and has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using strchr:

```
#include <cstring>
const char* vowel = "aeiouAEIOU";
//...
const char* p = strchr(vowel, str[i]);
if ( p )
{
    // p points to the vowel found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a comment but have too little reputation... it seems to me that the:

s[i]=vowels[k], k++

is the wrong way round, surely it should be "vowels[k] = s[i], k++" which could be improved to "vowels[k++] = s[i]". And the same for consonant of course.

In addition, before you carry out the strcat you should add a terminating zero character to both strings:

```
vowels[k] = (char)0;
consonant[f] = (char)0;
```

as otherwise the strings are not correctly terminated - you cannot assume that char arrays are initialised to all zeroes.

And of course Paul's suggestion above is a much neater way to detect a vowel...

Comment: thx for help l appreciate it I agree that  paul's idea is better but this was mine so l had to first try to fix mine and then use someone else :D