# Function for calculating the vowels in a string

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, lambda, stdstring

I wrote the function. But the teacher told me that in the 3<sup>rd</sup> parameters of the `std::count_if` function it is necessary to pass the *lambda* to find out if the letter is **vowel**.

I can not figure out how to transfer it there.

```
unsigned CalculateVowels(const std::string& str)
{
    const std::string& vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    unsigned count = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](int index) {return str[index] == vowels[index]; })

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vowels in string C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810895/vowels-in-string-c)

Comment: @ibnelaiq 
Is there a solution to my question? No no ... They do not use the count_if function.

Comment: You need to change `int index` to `char letter` and then return: `std::find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), letter) != v.end()`

Comment: @DimChtz and add `vowels` to the capture (with `[&]` for example)

Comment: @DimChtz I write - 
 unsigned count = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char ch) {std::find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), ch) != vowels.end(); });

Comment: Error C3493 'vowels' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified

Comment: @oksanavovl add vowels to the capture (with [&] for example)

Comment: the predicate is supposed to take an element not an index (see answer)

Comment: @prog-fh Correct? - unsigned count = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [&](char ch) {std::find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), ch) != vowels.end(); });

Comment: Yes, sorry you also need to capture `vowels`

Comment: @DimChtz unsigned count = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [&vowels](char ch) {std::find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), ch) != vowels.end(); });

Comment: Error C2451 conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal Tests

Comment: @oksanavovl You need to return inside the lambda, `return std::find ....`

Comment: @oksanavovl also, you should use `std::string::find()` instead of `std::find()`, eg: `size_t count = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [&vowels](char ch) { return vowels.find(ch) != std::string;;npos; });`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your lambda function is wrong.

It needs to check whether the current element from passed `str` matches any of the elements in `vowels`. You can use the standard algorithm [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) from `<algorithm>` header for this.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::any_of, std::count_if

auto CalculateVowels(const std::string& str)
{
    const std::string& vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    return std::count_if(
        str.cbegin(), // for each elements in the elements of passed `str`
        str.cend(), 
        [&vowels](const char element) 
        {
            // following checks `std::any_of` the `vowels` element
            // matches the element in the passed `str`
            return std::any_of(
                vowels.cbegin(), 
                vowels.cend(), 
                [element](const char vow) { return vow == element; }
            );

        }
    );
}
```

**([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FOgANKw5PMQZzgfz))**

---

If that too much for one line, break it into small pieces.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::find, std::count_if 

auto CalculateVowels(const std::string& str)
{
    const std::string& vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    // lambda to check whether passed `char` element is a match
    // of any of the `vowels`
    const auto isVowel = [&vowels](const char element_to_be_checked)
    {
        return std::any_of(
            vowels.cbegin(),
            vowels.cend(),
            [element_to_be_checked](const char vow)
            {
                return vow == element_to_be_checked;
            }
        );
    };
    // now simply `std::count_if` the element `isVowel`
    return std::count_if(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), isVowel);
}
```

---

Or like *@DimChtz* tried to explain in the comments, using [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)
or even better as *@RemyLebeau* suggested, using [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

```
#include <string>    // std::string::find
#include <algorithm> // std::find, std::count_if 

auto CalculateVowels(const std::string& str)
{
    const std::string& vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    const auto isVowel = [&vowels](const char element_to_be_checked)
    {
        // return std::find(vowels.cbegin(), vowels.cend(), element_to_be_checked) != vowels.cend();
        // or using `std::string::find`
        return vowels.find(element_to_be_checked) != std::string::npos;
    };
    return std::count_if(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), isVowel);
}
```

**([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aRrJIINVEz8FIBAl))**

Comment: `std::count_if(..., [isVowel](const char element) { return isVowel(element); } );` should be `std::count_if(..., isVowel);` And I would use `std::string::find()` instead of `std::find()`